# opencv "C" methods in Opencv SDK for Android

Tags: android, c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I have downloaded opencv2.4.2 Android SDK for Android development. I need to convert some Opencv "C" code to android-opencv. But I coulnd find any "C" functions in android-opencv. I could see only "CPP" functions in Android opencv.

For Example, `"detectmultiscale"` is there in the library but I couldnt find `"CvHaardetectobjects"`. Moreover I couldnt find any function that starts with `"Cv"`.

As I am used with "C" functions it would be good if I have same functions in Android-opencv also. Is it possible to get or only we have CPP methods in android opencv.?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you have installed OpenCV for Android you have Java Classes and Methods to be used for your purposes; if you really want to use C++ objects you have to go to developing in NDK...

BUT in your case, indeed there is no Java   `CvHaardetectobjects` on OpenCv for android; but in this case you can load an HaarCascade into a `CascadeClassifier`, after that you can use `detectMultiScale` to perform a detection based on the HaarCascade.

And you get the same results of `CvHaardetectobjects`.

See the code below:

```
/////////////Load the HaarCascade file into the clsssifier 
try {
        InputStream is3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_mcs_mouth);
        File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml");
        FileOutputStream os3 = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        Log.e("","Non c'è problema PRIMA della lettura del file");
        while ((bytesRead = is3.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os3.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is3.close();
        os3.close();
        Log.e("","Non c'è problema con la lettura del file");
        mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (mJavaDetector.empty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
        mJavaDetector = null;
        } else
        Log.e(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());


        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade. Exception thrown: " + e);
        }
    //////Call detectMultiScale with the Detector that contains the cascade     
        mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mat,MapofRect,1.15,4,0,new Size(25,15),new Size(face.width(),face.height()/2));
```

Comment: @2vision2 if the answer was useful please remember to accept it by checking the green check on the left. If not please ask more.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV for Android is based on the C++ functions so you will have better luck finding the relation between C++/Python <---> Android/Java.

You can also browse the Android/Java [functions here.](http://docs.opencv.org/java/)

Also, some stuff might have been deprecated and CvHaardetectobjects looks like one of those. It seems to have been replaced with [C++: CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) or  [Java: CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html).